# android dropbox authentication and upload in different activities

Tags: java, android, authentication, upload, dropbox

I am trying to upload a file from dropbox in another activity from where i autenticate to dropbox. I have this RegisterActivity.java where the user registers and then later when the registration is completed the webbrowser comes up and the user has to allow the dropbox authentication.

later in my app on another activity the user is going to upload a video to dropbox. the upload is made by ASyncTask and works well. The problem is now that i dont want to reauthenticate again. How do i fix that? Is it on the same session or do i start a new session? Now Iam trying to use the sam mDBApi form RegisterAcitivity but i think that is wrong. The keys are stored in the storeKeys() method and saves them in SharedPreferences.

Thank you very much in advance

Here is my RegisterActivity in pastebin which works. http://pastebin.com/K06JUWXv

Here is the activity that where i call my ASyncTask UploadFile:

```
public class ShowVideo extends Activity{

    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi = RegisterActivity.mDBApi;
    private String[] storedKeys = getKeys();
    UploadFile upload;
    public static String path = "";
    public static String fileName;
    private VideoView ww;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //Forces landscape orientation which is what the camera uses.
        setContentView(R.layout.showvideo);
        Button yesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        Button noButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NoButton);

        Button dbButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dropboxButton);
        dbButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(v.getId() == R.id.dropboxButton){
                    if (mDBApi.getSession().isLinked() == true){
                        Log.d("ShowVideo", "TRUE");
                    }
                    if (mDBApi.getSession().isLinked() == false){
                        Log.d("ShowVideo", "FALSE");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        yesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.yesButton){
                UploadFile upload = new UploadFile(ShowVideo.this,mDBApi,path);
                upload.execute();
                }
            }
        });

        noButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View w) {
                        File file = new File(path);
                        boolean deleted = false;
                        deleted = file.delete();
                        Log.e("TAG", Boolean.toString(deleted));
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ShowVideo.this, CaptureVideo.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        ww = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.satisfiedVideoView);
        path = getRealPathFromURI(CaptureVideo.uriVideo);
        fileName = getFileNameFromUrl(path);

        //AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(new AppKeyPair(ret[0], ret[1]), AccessType.APP_FOLDER);
        //mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
    }

    private void playVideo(){
        ww.setVideoURI(CaptureVideo.uriVideo);
        ww.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        ww.start();
        ww.requestFocus();
    }
    public static String getFileNameFromUrl(String path) {
        String[] pathArray = path.split("/");
        return pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    /**DROPBOX-METHOD------------------------------------------*/

    private String[] getKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
        String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
        if (key != null && secret != null) {
            String[] ret = new String[2];
            ret[0] = key;
            ret[1] = secret;
            return ret;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

Here is my ASyncTask if you would take a look at that. Shouldn't be needed.

```
public class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dDBApi;
    Context dContext;
    private String SAVE_PATH;

    public UploadFile(Context context,DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi, String path) {
        dContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        dDBApi = mDBApi;
        SAVE_PATH = path;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(SAVE_PATH);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Entry newEntry = dDBApi.putFileOverwrite("/GAMES/GAME_BETWEEN_USER_A_USER_B/" + "PresentVideo.mp4", inputStream, file.length(), null); 
        } 

        catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Another Exception:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Another Exception:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```